# How to disable close fullscreen touchscreen gesture on Gnome (Fedora)?

Tags: fedora, gnome, touchscreen, fullscreen, gestures

I'm building a touchscreen project on Fedora 31 (using Gnome 3) that requires a fullscreen Unity3D window that the user cannot close using the touchscreen.

I could disable most of the multi-touch gestures with several Gnome extensions (Disable Gestures, Block Caribou). Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to disable the (single-finger) drag down from top gesture, that exits the fullscreen mode of any app (works for Firefox, Unity3D, etc.).

Switching the desktop environment solves the problem (KDE Plasma, Xfce), but the touchscreen support of other enviroments is just not as good as in Gnome 3.

Does anyone have an idea, how do disable this gesture in Gnome 3?

Answer (score 4):

This post by u/katastrophal instructs [how to disable the fullscreen exit gesture](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/ci6tf4/turn_off_touch_gesture_input_in_gnome_328ubuntu/). Given, that the *Disable Gesture* extension is installed, one needs to change the following section in file ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/disable-gestures@mattbell.com.au/extension.js from

```
function enable() {
    global.stage.get_actions().forEach(a => a.enabled = false);
}
```

to

```
function enable() {
    global.stage.get_actions().forEach(a => a.enabled = false);

    let disableUnfullscreenGesture = () => {
        global.stage.get_actions().forEach(a => { if (a != this) a.enabled = false;});
    }
    global.display.connect('notify::focus-window', disableUnfullscreenGesture);
    global.display.connect('in-fullscreen-changed', disableUnfullscreenGesture);
}
```

Tested successfully in Gnome version 3.36.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Hi. Im losing my mind over this, I've a kiosk application and users keep going out of fullscreen mode because of multitouch gestures. I tried everything here, both the original and the modified version of the extension, to no avail. Any ideas? Ubuntu 18.04 here.

Comment: Can you verify that the three fingers pinch gesture and the four fingers swipe gesture are still active?

Is the extension actually enabled? Check with `gnome-extensions list` the status of installed extensions.

Alternatively, install gnome-tweaks by `apt-get install gnome-tweaks`, run `gnome-tweaks` and check if the extension is running. You may decrease the number of workspaces to one static as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I finally found the problem. It was that despite the system was indeed running Ubuntu 18.04, it was a modified version that came with unity (actual unity, not gnome looking like unity) as default front, so all the (gnome) patches I applied had no effect. Only after I realized this I was able to switch to real gnome front, which solved my problem. Now users can't escape fullscreen and the extensions became active. Disabling the gestures in unity required patching the source code and recompiling it, which thankfully I managed to dodge by making gnome the default front. Thanks!